# Excel - multiple value search across multiple columns or one column with multiple values

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-columns, vlookup, multiple-value

I have 7 criteria = TMO-1 through to TMO-7

I have two scenarios to search from.

i have either got a single excel with TMO-6, TMO-201, TMO-67,... etc (some have a lot of values)

or i have split the cell up so the values are all in individual cells such that [TMO-6][TMO-201][TMO-67] etc

I have tried two equations from each. for the first one (the preferred solution) i have tried:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("TMO-1",AB8),0) > 0, "TMO-1",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("TMO-2",AB8),0) > 0, "TMO-2", "false"))
```

the problem with that is it finds anything that starts with TMO-1, so will show true if TMO-12 is in the cell.

For option 2 i tried:

```
=IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-1, TMO-1, IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-2, TMO-2, IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-3, TMO-3,IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-4, TMO-4, IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-5, TMO-5, IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-6, TMO-6, IF(AB9:AR9=TMO-7, TMO-7, "N/A")))))))
```

and i get the error #spill

any ideas ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a formula if the data are either in a single cell or across cells.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- ms365 (Hence the `#SPILL` error);
- The option between concatenated values or seperated (hence `AB8` against `AB9:AR9`);
- All numbers are prepended with `TMO-`;
- You are looking for the 1st match in sequence (1-7);
- If no match is found, you want to return "Not Found".

---

First thing that came to mind is to just keep the comma-seperated data in `AB8` and use a simple trick to concatenate the delimiters with the sequence:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("-"&SEQUENCE(7)&",",A1&","))
```

To put that in practice, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("X",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-"&SEQUENCE(7)&",",A1&",")),"X"),0),"Not Found")
```

---

**Other options:**

```
=@IFERROR(SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(.,5)<8]")),"Not Found")
```

Or, using the insider BETA-functions:

```
=LET(X,MIN(--DROP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",", "),,1)),IF(X<8,"TMO-"&X,"Not Found"))
```